How to be notified of Azure Devops degradation automatically via email....like service health alerts?
I am trying to get a degradation email as per geography for Azure Devops ....something similar to Azure Service Health Alerts...any idea??
Because i have checked azure devops is not part of resources can be used under service health of azure

You can view the Azure DevOps events from this page.
If you want to receive notification on your email-box when new events reported or have updates on the events, you can try like as below:

Open your Micrsoft Office Outlook email-box, On the left navigation bar, you can see the option "RSS Subscriptions".

Right click on the "RSS Subscriptions", select "Add a New RSS Feed...".

On the pop-up window, enter the URL "https://status.dev.azure.com/_rss" and click 'Add'. Then click 'Yes'.

After above steps, you can see a folder "Azure DevOps - Recent Events" added under "RSS Subscriptions". In this folder, you can receive the notifications of Azure DevOps events reported recently.





this hack works, thanks @Bright Ran-MSFT
